# Why Spring Boot embedded tomcat can't start on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, google-compute-engine, centos7

I tried to launch a spring boot application on a GCE instance running CentOS 7 but it seems to hang just after finishing the web app initialisation but before showing the final "Server started successfully message". The last message logged to console is:

```
2016-03-18 07:34:04.802  INFO 1175 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet : 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

I suspect it has something to do with [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=172) reported on GCE issue tracker.

The same application is starting without any issue on Amazon EC2 instance running Amazon AMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the tomcat was stuck on creation of `SecureRandom` instance

```
 [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [568,680] milliseconds.
```

The issue is discussed in tomcat documentation on [Entropy Source](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Entropy_Source)

Adding `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` to jvm parameters when launching spring boot application fixed the issue.

**Why this happens on CentOS but not amazon linux?**
To quote from [BEA Logic SIP Server documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html)

> The library used for random number generation in Sun's JVM relies on /dev/random by default for UNIX platforms.

and

> .. on some operating systems /dev/random waits for a certain amount of "noise" to be generated on the host machine before returning a result.

Comment: `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` Where should i add this code? Is it into Application.Properties?

Comment: @forguta You can provide this parameter when you invoke `java` from from command line, for example: `java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar my-springboot-app.jar`